# how to change one of nested objects with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have some objects in state and i want to add key/value into one of my objects, for example add key/value for object that the id is 13.

See the photo attached.

I can use setState but i don't know how to select object that id is '13' and update it with setState.

How can i combine filter or map with setState ?
my setState code is below but i don't know how can change state that id is 13

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  carpets: [...prevState.carpets, this.state.carpet],
}));
```

[image: Click Here For See My Objects Picture]

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.find()`, the method can help your for find something you want in a array. If you want more information you can read [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: When mapping your state into a new state object you can check the id property, if it matches, update/add the new value property. If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example we can better assist you.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  carpets: prevState.carpets.map(carpet => (
    carpet.id === 13
      ? { ...carpet, key: value }
      : carpet
  ))
}));
```